# AWS X-ray local get segment data

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-xray

I have local xray daemon running on my mac and I am testing a graphql lambda the instrument traces. I am using serverless offline for testing the lambda. The daemon logs show `Successfully sent batch of 9 segments (0.318 seconds)` but I am not able to see any traces in my console. Also, what other ways are there to view the segments that are being relayed. I wanted to test my xray instrumenting but there is no way to know what segments are being trace and how. I do set my set profile before running the local daemon here is my serverless.yml, just in case I am missing something there

```
service: graphql-lambda

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  tracing:
    lambda: true
    apiGateway: true
  iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - "xray:PutTraceSegments"
      - "xray:PutTelemetryRecords"
    Resource: "*"
functions:
  graphql:
    handler: build/server.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: graphql
          method: any
          cors: true
    environment:
      AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS: "127.0.0.1:2000"
      AWS_XRAY_CONTEXT_MISSING: "LOG_ERROR"

plugins:
 - serverless-offline
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for trying xray. Please refer to xray daemon config to ensure the segments are sent to to correct account/region https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-daemon#credential-configuration

Also, you can enable debug log for daemon to get more information.

Comment: I logged actual segments by adding some logs to daemon code. it turned out that I wasn't sending the correct segments. There were some orphaned segments. I wonder if there is a way to add a warning for that in daemon logs?

Comment: Unfortunately, the orphaned segments have to be detected from service end. The distributed clients are not able to know whether the parent segment is missing. 
Refer to [Example Independent subsegment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-api-segmentdocuments.html#api-segmentdocuments-subsegments)